# How to download a tarball with files that changed on a pull request on Github?

Tags: git, github

There's this 3 year old set of changes on a pull request on GitHub over a complex project (a WebKit fork). The main tree code has changed a lot since then, and rebasing the changes is not really an option anymore.

I was hoping to be able to download a tarball with only the modified files. On GitHub's website if I open the pull request I can see those files listed, but I couldn't find an option to download them all at the same time (and they're roughly 600 files). Is there a way to do that (maybe with git archive or something else)?

Comment: You're going to have to give usable, concrete details about your working environment and constraints. Git's not a deployment server, it's not set up to make working with arbitrary deployments easy, it's set up to make working within Git's environment productive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create an archive of just the modified files.  GitHub can create archives for the entire revision, as can `git archive`.

You could do something like `git diff --name-only BASE...HEAD` to find the files that were modified and then, with a complete tarball, tell `tar` to extract only those files into whatever directory you wanted.